# How to set an Expressjs response to XML?

Tags: node.js, express

I try:

```
req.accepts('application/xml');
res.header('Content-Type','text/xml');
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

but the response always: `text/html`, see this image:

[image]

Comment: Show more code. Where in your app are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(XML DATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set content-type for all responses using express like

```
  app.use(function(req,res,next){
   res.setHeader('content-type','text/html');
   next();
  });
```

I hope it will help you.